# How delete knows, where the object starts in the memory?

Tags: c++

Consider following code:

```
class Base1 { public: int a1; };
class Base2 { public: int a2; };
class Foo: public Base1, public Base2 {}

int main() {
   Foo *foo = new Foo();
   Base2 *b = foo; 
   delete b; // note pointer foo != pointer b
}
```

How delete knows, where the memory, which should be freed, begins?

Since all the classes contain only atomic integers, is virtual destructor needed in this particular case?

Comment: Only pass the pointers returned by `new` (or a null pointer) to `delete`. Otherwise you have undefined behavior.

Comment: Crashes on my machine.

Answer (score 6):

> is virtual destructor needed in this particular case?

Yes. Deleting an object through a pointer to a base with non-virtual destructor has undefined behaviour.

> How delete knows, where the object starts in the memory?

In case of non-virtual destructor, you pass the starting address to the operator (or if you don't, then you have UB), so there's no mystery.

In case of virtual destructor, virtual dispatch is used. The compiler will somehow implement it to work correctly. Typically, a "vptr" is used.

Comment: There are no destructors in the code and even the members don't have destructors. Are you sure, I have to create an artificial virtual one? Also, I would like to know, how the "compiler somehow..." works.